# Can't pip microsoft azure-cognitiveservices-speech?

Tags: python, pip, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-speech-api

Following the guide here to install the microsoft azure text to speech SDK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstart-python#install-the-speech-sdk

It says to run 
`pip install azure-cognitiveservices-speech`
, but unfortunately this returns

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement azure->cognitiveservices-speech (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for >azure-cognitiveservices-speech

I've tried adding the version # at the end with ==1.2.0, and also adding --pre.  So:

`python -m pip install azure-cognitiveservices-speech --pre`

`python -m pip install azure-cognitiveservices-speech==1.2.0`.

I was able to use `python -m pip install azure` and it downloaded a whole bunch of modules, but not the cognitive services one. I've tried on python 2.7 and on python 3.7 and I've also installed **Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017**. If anybody has any ideas on how to install this module it will be much appreciated.

Here is the pypi link: https://pypi.org/project/azure-cognitiveservices-speech/

Comment: `azure-cognitiveservices-speech` version 1.2.0 [is available](https://pypi.org/project/azure-cognitiveservices-speech/1.2.0/#files) for Python 3.5, 3.6 and 3.7 for MacOS, Linux and Windows, 64 bit only. What is your Python version? Check if it is 64-bit, not 32: `python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"`

Comment: thanks, that was it..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`azure-cognitiveservices-speech` version 1.2.0 is available for Python **3.5**, **3.6** and **3.7** for MacOS, Linux and Windows, **64 bits only**.

What is your Python version? Check it is 64 bits, not 32 bits:

Console/Shell:

```
python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"
```