# cannot install Azure-cognitiveservices-speech on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: azure, raspberry-pi3, ubuntu-18.04, azure-cognitive-services

good evening.
I try to install Azure-cognitiveservices-speech on Ubuntu Mate 18.04, but I receive error:

**Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement azure->cognitiveservices-speech (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for >azure-cognitiveservices-speech**

I have Ubuntu MATE 18.04 64bit on Raspberry 3B+ with installed

libssl1.0.0

libasound2

Do you have any suggestion for me?

thank you for your support.

Comment: referencing an older [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54425580/cant-pip-microsoft-azure-cognitiveservices-speech) with similar error along with current system [requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-sdk?tabs=linux%2Cubuntu%2Cios-xcode%2Cmac-xcode%2Candroid-studio#get-the-speech-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, the mostly reason is you are not using the workable version of Pyhton.

azure-cognitiveservices-speech version 1.2.0 works only for Python 3.5, 3.6 and 3.7.And you should be under the system including MacOS, Linux and Windows, 64 bits.

Please check your version and make sure you are under 64 bits.

Try:

python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"