# Unable to install pip azure-cognitiveservices-speech within a docker container

Tags: python, azure, docker, pip, text-to-speech

### Original Issue

I'm unable to install azure-cognitiveservices-speech within a docker container using pip. My container is running fine and is able to install all other packages (django, google-cloud-translate, boto3 for example) without any issues using the following dockerfile.

#### Original DockerFile

```
FROM python:3.8.2
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
COPY . /code/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY entrypoint.sh /code/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod u+x /code/entrypoint.sh
```

#### Original requirements.txt

```
amqp==5.0.2
asgiref==3.3.1
billiard==3.6.3.0
celery==5.0.4
click==7.1.2
click-didyoumean==0.0.3
click-plugins==1.1.1
click-repl==0.1.6
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.1.3
django-crispy-forms==1.9.2
django-filter==2.4.0
django-rest-auth==0.9.5
djangorestframework==3.12.2
kombu==5.0.2
Markdown==3.3.3
prompt-toolkit==3.0.8
psycopg2==2.8.6
pytz==2020.4
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
vine==5.0.0
wcwidth==0.2.5
google-cloud-translate==3.0.2
django-storages==1.9.1
gunicorn==20.0.4
boto3==1.16.43
```

However, when azure-cognitiveservices-speech is added to this list, I am receiving the following error:

#### Original error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement azure-cognitiveservices-speech (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for azure-cognitiveservices-speech
```

*I have tried specifying the specific version of the module too.*

#### Attempted Solutions

I have simplified the dockerfile and specified running on Ubuntu alongside installing some dependencies that I have read from other resources (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/issues/747) may be required for the azure-cognitiveservices-speech package, however to no avail.

#### Adjusted DockerFile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libssl1.0.0 \
    libasound2 \
    python3.7

RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install azure-cognitiveservices-speech
ADD . /code/
```

*I have also tried multiple versions of Python within both versions of the docker container.*
However, I am still receiving the original error seen above.

Following this answer ([Can't pip microsoft azure-cognitiveservices-speech?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54425580/cant-pip-microsoft-azure-cognitiveservices-speech)) I have run the original container and entered the terminal confirmed that I am running a suitable 64 bit version of python.

```
# python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"
64
```

Does anyone have a solution/appropriate enviroment to run this package within a container? Apologies for the long question, I have tried a whole host of things to get this package installed. Am I missing something fundamental?

Alternatively, is there another way to access this API without installing this package?

#### Additional info

I am running this container on a M1 macbook pro, however I have attempted it on an older intel mac to see if this may be the problem and I am still seeing the same error.

Comment: Where do you create the image? There is no problem to install the package `azure-cognitiveservices-speech` on my side.

Comment: Hi @CharlesXu thanks for taking a look. Your comment has made me look a bit further into this and I've updated the question to give some more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I seem to have finally got this working now. In honesty, I'm not sure I fully understand what has finally caused this pip install to start working. However, this is my first question here and I think it's best to just post what has fixed it for me in case anyone else runs into it.

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 ubuntu:18.04 AS myubuntu
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libssl1.0.0 \
    libasound2 \
    python3.6

RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
ADD . /code/
ENV LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8
RUN pip3 install -r ./requirements.txt
```

*Seems I needed to specify the platform (potentially a known error with [Apple M1 preview version of docker](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/apple-m1/)), install the required ubuntu packages for azure-cognitiveservices-speech and then set the ENV variables as this was also causing an error*.

Then build the image (*with specifying network=host*), tag it and the reference the local image within my docker-compose file as so.

```
docker build --network=host -t testinstall2 .
docker tag testinstall2:latest testinstall:staging
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
   
services:
  db:
    # restart: always
    image: postgres:13.1
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=
      - POSTGRES_USER=
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  web:
    image: testinstall:staging
    entrypoint: /code/entrypoint.sh
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    env_file: &envfile
      - SecretKeys/env.env
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - broker
  celery:
    image: testinstall:staging
    restart: "no"
    command : celery -A MyProject worker -l info
    env_file: *envfile
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    depends_on: 
      - db
      - broker
  celery-beat:
    image: testinstall:staging
    restart: "always"
    command: celery -A MyProject beat -l info
    env_file: *envfile
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    depends_on:
      - db
      - broker
  broker:
    image: rabbitmq:3
    env_file: *envfile
    ports: 
      - 5672:5672




volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Following this all my containers and celery workers run as expected with the azure package. I would still be interested to understand what exactly was causing this if anyone has any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

I also use a MacBook with an ARM chip, adding `--platform=linux/amd64` to the official Python Docker image solved the problem for me.

Also make sure to install the latest version of the package as support from [different platforms is limited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54428357/1360476).

`azure-cognitiveservices-speech==1.19.0` worked at the time of this answer.